# Angular 5 :Trigger mat-autocomplete on pressing a particular key

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5

I am trying to come up with something like the tagging feature on Facebook i.e whenever '@' key is pressed my autocomplete should be triggered and I should be able to see the option corresponding to the data typed post '@'.

I am unable to bind the autocomplete on keydown(or any key event)

Any suggestion on how to achieve this functionality would be appreciated, My last resort is coming up with my own autocomplete module

Comment: Show the tried code or Provide Stackblitz if possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do the following to accomplish this.

Create a `ViewChild` to get reference to the `MatAutocompleteTrigger`

```
@ViewChild(MatAutocompleteTrigger) _auto: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
```

Create a `HostListener` to set the `formControl` value to `@` and open the panel when the `@` key is pressed.

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.key == '@') {
      this.stateCtrl.setValue('@');
      this._auto.openPanel();
    }
  }
```

**Stackblitz**

In this stackblitz, click the view to set focus or the event will not trigger the `HostListener`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4x3zte?embed=1&file=app/autocomplete-overview-example.ts

Comment: This does not answer how I can to assign auto-complete for just a part of form-field instead of replacing the data of entire field