# Trigger matAutocomplete programmatically

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'd like to trigger autocomplete only if a special character is written at the end of the input text.

E.g when the user types: '`@`', the autocomplete should appear.

This is my code:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input #myInput type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="myInput.value.slice(-1) == '@' ? auto : false">
</mat-form-field>

<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">{{option}}</mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

The autocompleate appears, but does disappear automatically.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 5 :Trigger mat-autocomplete on pressing a particular key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55379558/angular-5-trigger-mat-autocomplete-on-pressing-a-particular-key)

Answer (score 6):

This way worked with me.

Add `(keydown.@)="onKeydown($event)"` to html file

```
<mat-form-field>
  <input #myInput type="text" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto" (keydown.@)="onKeydown($event)" >
</mat-form-field>

<mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option">{{option}}</mat-option>
</mat-autocomplete>
```

In component ts file

```
@ViewChild(MatAutocompleteTrigger) autocomplete: MatAutocompleteTrigger;

onKeydown(e){
    this.autocomplete.openPanel();
  }
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-keyup-open-panel

Comment: did you try my demo?

Answer (score 0):

You can also read the trigger from the `<input>` field explicitly like this - which may be necessary if you have multiple search fields.

```
<input #searchAutocompleteTrigger="matAutocompleteTrigger" .../>
```

Then read the viewChild

```
// using the new signal based viewChild
searchAutocompleteTrigger = viewChild.required<MatAutocompleteTrigger>('searchAutocompleteTrigger');

// traditional @ViewChild    
@ViewChild('searchAutocompleteTrigger', { read: MatAutocompleteTrigger }) 
searchAutocompleteTrigger!: MatAutocompleteTrigger;
```